# How to check for the presence of specific values in a list?

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image: Excel problem]

- I have a specific ID (e.g., Alpha, Beta, Gamma), in column A  in one spreadsheet.
- A second spreadsheet has various values for each of the IDs, which are not sorted in any way (illustrated in columns E and F in the image).
- In my first spreadsheet, I want to create extra columns and check whether specific values for the IDs are present in my second spreadsheet: e.g., is Alpha present for Apple (yes / no) or Beta present for Orange (yes / no).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need countifs()

For the "Apple"

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(E:E,A3,F:F,"Apple"),1,0)
```

For the bean replace "Apple" with"Bean"

Comment: Hi - many thanks for the quick response ! Much appreciated - it works perfectly !! - if the encounter of "Apple" is now more than 1 per ID - how could I make it count (instead of 1/0) - the number of occassions ?

Comment: @Marc just use the COUNTIFS() part.

Comment: @Marc, just to clarify, the COUNTIFS count the qualifying values present.  The IF just looks at whether the count is zero or something else for False or True.